# Off[FinancialData::notent] fails on first run but works thereafter

Tags: warning-messages, curated-data

`Off[FinancialData::notent]` fails on first run but works thereafter. So what good is it in this case?  Is there a trick to force first time success?  I've tried "tricks" to my wit's end!

Comment: Closers: please leave this question open. The question may not be clear to everybody, but combined with the answer I find this a useful contribution to the site.

Answer (score 4):

Clearing `Attributes` and looking at the definition of the `FinancialData` reveals that it is just a stub that loads the corresponding paclet on the first evaluation:

```
ClearAttributes[FinancialData, {Protected, ReadProtected}]
FullDefinition@FinancialData
```

> ```
> FinancialData := 
>  System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[FinancialData], 
>    Hold[$FinancialDataSource, FinancialData], 
>    "DataPaclets`FinancialData`"] /; System`Dump`TestLoad
> ```

As you see from the definition, `FinancialData` initially has no `Message`s defined, so you cannot switch them off.

For getting `Off[FinancialData::notent]` working you should preload the `FinancialData` paclet (may be there is an easier way to do this, I do not know):

```
FinancialData[]; Off[FinancialData::notent]
```

Now it works as expected:

```
FinancialData::notent
```

> ```
> $Off["`1` is not a known entity, class, or tag for `2`. Use `2`[] for a list of entities."]
> ```

```
FinancialData["BMW"]
```

> ```
> FinancialData["BMW"]
> ```